# c++ array error C3646: 'jarArray' : unknown override specifier

Tags: c++, arrays, class, header-files

Another Easy one.....

I have an array of a object (jar) that I declared in the header (box).

```
#include "Jar.h"

using namespace std;



class box
{
public:
box();
void searchForPart(string part);


 private:


int numberOfJars;
Jar jarArray[50];
int count;
};
```

In the actual box constructor @ box.cpp, I populate the jar array by:

```
#include "Jar.h"
#include "Box.h"


.....

jarArray[] = {Jar("bolts"), Jar("Nuts"), Jar("screws"), Jar("drywallnails"), Jar("nails")};
```

I think I'm missing something in the declaration.  error C3646: 'jarArray' : unknown override specifier.  Any suggestion now what I"m missing ???

Comment: Where have you seen such syntax *jarArray[] = ...;* in C++? (or C)

Comment: @Roman B.: I think he got that from the syntax for initializing the array at it declaration: `Jar jarArray[] = {...}`. It makes sense, it's just not correct.

Comment: Now I'm getting...
error C2512: 'Jar' : no appropriate default constructor available  
even though I have a constructor for Jar that takes a string...

Comment: heck I can't even do JarArray[0] ={Jar("hello")};  Maybe I'm not referencing the Jar class correctly???
do I need anything else other than an #include jar.h in the box.cpp?

Comment: I think my error is in how I'm declaring Jar jarArray[50]; in the box header file. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you were working with C++11, I believe you could have done this:

```
Bar::Bar()
: jarArray({Jar("bolts"), Jar("Nuts"), Jar("screws"), Jar("drywallnails"), Jar("nails")})
{
    //...
}
```

However, with our beloved C++03, it comes down to

```
Bar::Bar()
{
    jarArray[0] = Jar("bolts");
    jarArray[1] = Jar("nuts");
    jarArray[2] = Jar("screws");
    jarArray[3] = Jar("drywallnails");
    jarArray[4] = Jar("nails");
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are under C++ 11:

```
Bar::Bar() : jarArray{Jar("bolts"), ... , Jar("screws")}{}
```

If not use a for loop, or equivalent.

<strike>But your problem probably is that Jar is not visible at Box.cpp.</strike>

jarArray is a member of Box. So you can just initialize it *out of the box* right? :)